# How to map out an irregular shape so it can be used as a sort of button

Tags: java, libgdx

[Language: Java]

I am trying to turn a set of countries on an image of a map into buttons.

I have tried to paint the image on paint.net. I paint each country with a different colour and then look for those rgb's, that way I have each countries x, y values and even a unique identifier (kind of). I was thinking that I could then iterate through a list of there points top see if I was clicking on them, but this feels like it would be dead inefficient.

I was also going to add boundary boxes to each country, but also add them inside to so that I could check for a collision much quicker (i.e. does this x,y and reside within this box?, no?, move on...)

A whole other way I thought of was find out the smallest boundry box of a country then store it as a 2D array i.e.

```
int [][] countryAsPixels = new int [width][height];
```

then I could store the image as a matrix like

```
0000000000
0000111000
0001111110
1111111111
1110000000
0000000000
```

so the 0 would be not on the country and the 1 would be. 
I thought this would be good because I could just go

```
public boolean hasHit(int x, int y){
    if(countryAsPixels[x][y] == 1){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

no looping through every pixel. Just one query. But now I have to store all these 0's which mean nothing. Is that wasteful in-terms of memory.

Note: My ultimate goal is to link all these countries together with a graph and also run the program using libGDX.

I was also thinking that I could dismantle the image into countries, like above, and then use those values to break down the non paineted image (original map image) then build each country onto the map manually. Would that be better than having a virtual overlay?

Comment: Use `JavaFX` as a technology, not `libGDX'. Create your shape using a ['Polyline'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polyline.html).

Comment: As a group, we already decided we were using libgdx. I don't think I will be able to change it. Some people are already working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea with colors is ok. But why you must iterate trough the list? You get a coordinates of click event. And you will have your "image map" as an table (2D array) so just collect the color at specific coordinates you acquired from click event. Probably you will have to do some conversion of coords.

Even easier solution would be to have (load) real image instead keeping color table. Use the LibGDX pixmaps.You can load image file directly into pixmap and then check color at specific coordinates.

To create pixmap by loading external image file:
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#Pixmap-com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle-

and then get pixed color with getPixel() method
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#getPixel-int-int-

Comment: Thanks, that is the best and worst answer. Best because it solves my problem easily, but worst because it has taken all the fun away.

Comment: sorry I did not know that was a thing.